# WPF MVVM - How to update multiple textblocks across multiple user controls when a single property gets updated in ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have multiple user controls that are tied to their respective ViewModels. There is a "Name" view/viewmodel pair, an "Id" view/viewmodel pair and a "Status" view. The purpose of the Status view is to display in real time what is being entered in the name and id input textboxes and also to display the value after typing is done. I tied the textbox in the Status view to the name property in the Name viewmodel, but it isn't updating, despite the setter breakpoint being hit. It shows the default value of the Name property, but wouldn't update.

Here are the files:

**NameViewModel.cs**

```
    class NameViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private String _name= "xyzzy";

        public String Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                _name = value; 
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EnterName.xaml** - the view where one enters the name

```
<Window x:Class="Simple_WPF_Application.EnterName"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:Simple_WPF_Application.ViewModels" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewmodels:NameViewModel}"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Enter Name" Height="239" Width="368">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="369" Height="235" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <TextBox x:Name="txtbox" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="134,104,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="173" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" Text="{Binding Path=Name,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.509,1.32">
            <TextBox.BindingGroup>
                <BindingGroup/>
            </TextBox.BindingGroup>
        </TextBox>
        <Label Content="Name" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="87,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFF9F5F5"/>
                    <Button x:Name="btn_back" Content="Back" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="87,149,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="99" Click="btn_back_Click"/>
                    <Button x:Name="btn_continue" Content="Continue" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="208,149,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click" IsEnabled="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="99"/>
        <Label Content="Please Enter Name" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="108,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFFBF7F7" FontSize="20"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Status.xaml** - Where the name and id are shown

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Simple_WPF_Application"
        xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:Simple_WPF_Application.ViewModels" x:Class="Simple_WPF_Application.Status"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Status" Height="139" Width="254">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="Name:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="35,24,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label Content="Id:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="35,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txt_status_name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="84,32,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Text="{Binding Path=Name,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <TextBox.DataContext>
                <ViewModels:NameViewModel/>
            </TextBox.DataContext>
        </TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="txt_status_id" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="84,58,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Id view and viewmodel are similar to name.

What can I do that will update the status user while the name or id textbox is being typed in and also persist the value when the view is closed and opened again?

I tried to bind the status view textbox to the Name viewmodel property, but it just won't update. This is the code:

```
 <TextBox x:Name="txt_status_name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="84,32,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Text="{Binding Path=Name,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}">
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you multiple Views where you are "binding" in xaml you Textbox datacontext to the ViewModel? If so, then I have to disappoint you - each of those datacontext binding is creating a new instance of you VM class. In other words they are not sharing same data. My suggestion is to look into storing the inputs in a service and in VM receiving the data )

Comment: You could try to create ONE instance in code and set this manually (from code) on both forms - that should work,